# nested Annotation List in Scala

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-2.8, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Help,

how do i do stuff like the following in Scala?

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.ScriptAssert

@ScriptAssert.List({
    @ScriptAssert(script = "...", lang = "javascript"),
    @ScriptAssert(script = "...", lang = "javascript")})
```

Answer (score 9):

The correct syntax is as follows (`Array(...)` for arrays, `new Nested(..)` for nested annotations):

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.ScriptAssert

@ScriptAssert.List(Array(
  new ScriptAssert(script = "...", lang = "javascript"),
  new ScriptAssert(script = "...", lang = "javascript")))
class Test
```

Comment: Did you try it? Using Scala 2.8, this works for me. I just got the syntax wrong in my initial answer, but now it's corrected.

Comment: I did try (against scala 2.8 and hibernate validator), and it doesn't work. Did you try?

Comment: Your code gives "error: org.hibernate.validator.constraints.ScriptAssert does not have a constructor: new ScriptAssert(script = "...", lang = "javascript")))"

Comment: You need to put validation-api into the classpath. Here's the command I used for compiling the thing: `~/scala/dist/bin/scalac -cp /Users/luc/Downloads/hib/hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/luc/Downloads/hib/validation-api-1.0.CR5.jar test.scala`